# Including project in build depending on setting's value, e.g. scalaVersion?

Tags: sbt

I have a Scala project that is divided into several subprojects:

```
lazy val core: Seq[ProjectReference] = Seq(common, json_scalaz7, json_scalaz)
```

I'd like to make the `core` lazy val conditional on the Scala version I'm currently using, so I tried this:

```
lazy val core2: Seq[ProjectReference] = scalaVersion {
    case "2.11.0" => Seq(common, json_scalaz7)
    case _        => Seq(common, json_scalaz7, json_scalaz)
}
```

Simply speaking, I'd like to exclude `json_scalaz` for Scala 2.11.0 (when the value of the `scalaVersion` setting is `"2.11.0"`).

This however gives me the following compilation error:

```
[error] /home/diego/work/lift/framework/project/Build.scala:39: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : sbt.Project.Initialize[Seq[sbt.Project]]
[error]  required: Seq[sbt.ProjectReference]
[error]   lazy val core2: Seq[ProjectReference] = scalaVersion {
[error]                                                        ^
[error] one error found
```

Any idea how to solve this?

**Update**

I'm using sbt version 0.12.4
This project is the Lift project, which compiles against `"2.10.0", "2.9.2", "2.9.1-1", "2.9.1" and now we are working on getting it to compile with 2.11.0`. So creating a compile all task would not be practical, as it would take a really long time.

**Update 2**

I'm hoping there is something like this:

```
lazy val scala_xml    = "org.scala-lang.modules"     %% "scala-xml"         % "1.0.1"
lazy val scala_parser = "org.scala-lang.modules"     %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.0.1"

...

lazy val common =
  coreProject("common")
    .settings(description := "Common Libraties and Utilities",
            libraryDependencies ++= Seq(slf4j_api, logback, slf4j_log4j12),
            libraryDependencies <++= scalaVersion {
              case "2.11.0" => Seq(scala_xml, scala_parser)
              case _ => Seq()
            }
  )
```

but for the projects list

Note how depending on the scala version, I add the scala_xml and scala_parser_combinator libraries

You can see the complete build file [here](https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/diego_scala_2_11/project/Build.scala)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Cross building a project

> Simply speaking, I'd like to exclude json_scalaz for Scala 2.11.0

The built-in support in sbt for this is called cross building, which is described in [Cross-Building a Project](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Cross-Build.html#cross-building-a-project). Here's from the section with a bit of correction:

> Define the versions of Scala to build against in the `crossScalaVersions` setting. For example, in a .sbt build definition:

```
crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.10.4", "2.11.0")
```

> To build against all versions listed `crossScalaVersions`, prefix the action to run with `+`. For example:

```
> +compile
```

### Multiple-project builds

sbt also has built-in support to aggregate tasks across multiple projects, which is described [Aggregation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html#aggregation). If what you need eventually is normal built-in tasks like `compile` and `test`, you could set up a dummy aggregate without `json_scalaz`.

```scala
lazy val withoutJsonScalaz = (project in file("without-json-scalaz")).
  .aggregate(liftProjects filterNot {_ == json_scalaz}: _*)
```

From the shell, you should be able to use this as:

```
> ++2.11.0
> project withoutJsonScalaz
> test
```

### Getting values from multiple scopes

Another feature you might be interested in is [ScopeFilter](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks.html#getting-values-from-multiple-scopes). This has the ability to traverse multiple projects beyond usual aggregation and cross building. You would need to create a setting whose type is `ScopeFilter` and set it based on `scalaBinaryVersion.value`. With scope filters, you can do:

```scala
val coreProjects = settingKey[ScopeFilter]("my core projects")

val compileAll = taskKey[Seq[sbt.inc.Analysis]]("compile all")

coreProjects := {
  (scalaBinaryVersion.value) match {
    case "2.10" => ScopeFilter(inProjects(common, json_scalaz7, json_scalaz))
  }
}

compileAll := compileAllTask.value

lazy val compileAllTask = Def.taskDyn {
  val f = coreProjects.value
  (compile in Compile) all f
}
```

In this case `compileAll` would have the same effect as `+compile`, but you could aggregate the result and do something interesting like [sbt-unidoc](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-unidoc).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but cross compiling this project would just take too long, I updated the question with more details.

Comment: What are you going to do with the list of projects once you get it? If you're going to run tasks, isn't `ScopeFilter` what you want?

Comment: The issue I'm trying to solve is: the json_scalaz project depends on scalaz6, which is not built for scala 2.11.0, but it is built for <=2.10.x. In the project we run test, compile, generate docs, etc. so I'm hoping that when I do ++2.11.0, json_scalaz is omitted from everything, as If I deleted the project, but if I do ++2.10.4, json_scalaz comes back in as If I added to the list. Does it make sense? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Which project are you running `test`, `compile` etc from? The root project aka `lift-framework` or in individual subprojects? I've update the answer to include how to make an alternative aggregate.

Comment: I ended up doing something based on the "Multiple-project builds" solution.